# Check if method defined on mixee class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

We have a module to handle canceling models. It's clean, works nice, but we've run in to an issue where a class we want to mix it in to already has our module methods (`cancel!`, etc) defined.

We tried to come up with new names to avoid collisions, but everything seems less-than-ideal, and we like the cleanness of calling `cancel!`. So, we've decided we want to do something like:

```
def cancel!
  cancelly_stuff
  if class.parent.respond_to(:cancel!) super
end
```

However, it's a module, so the class we're mixing it in to is not `class.parent`. I was unable to google how to reference the mixee-class of a module.

Comment: I deleted my answer because I realized I don't understand the question. Are the class' `cancel!` and module's `cancel!` identical? Is `cancelly_stuff` a new method or is it related to the `cancel!` you propose to overwrite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I come with another answer to your post, now using `prepend` instead of `include` (only for ruby 2.x). The first is including at the top of the ancestry chain, since the second goes after the class.

Let see how it works at the irb console:

```
~/rails/learn/ruby (main) > module A
~/rails/learn/ruby (main) |   def cancel!
~/rails/learn/ruby (main) |     puts 'cancel from m:A'
~/rails/learn/ruby (main) |     super if defined? super
~/rails/learn/ruby (main) |   end  
~/rails/learn/ruby (main) | end  
=> :cancel!
~/rails/learn/ruby (main) > class C
~/rails/learn/ruby (main) |   prepend A
~/rails/learn/ruby (main) |   def cancel!
~/rails/learn/ruby (main) |     puts 'cancel from c:C'
~/rails/learn/ruby (main) |   end  
~/rails/learn/ruby (main) | end  
=> :cancel!
~/rails/learn/ruby (main) > C.ancestors
=> [
    [0] #<Class:0x000000035421f0>::A,
    [1] #<Class:0x000000035421f0>::C < Object,
    [2] Object < BasicObject,
    [3] PP::ObjectMixin,
    [4] Kernel,
    [5] BasicObject
]
~/rails/learn/ruby (main) > C.new.cancel!
cancel from m:A
cancel from c:C
=> nil
~/rails/learn/ruby (main) > class D
~/rails/learn/ruby (main) |   include A
~/rails/learn/ruby (main) |   def cancel!
~/rails/learn/ruby (main) |     puts 'cancel from c:D'
~/rails/learn/ruby (main) |     super if defined? super
~/rails/learn/ruby (main) |   end  
~/rails/learn/ruby (main) | end  
=> :cancel!
~/rails/learn/ruby (main) > D.ancestors
=> [
    [0] #<Class:0x000000035421f0>::D < Object,
    [1] #<Class:0x000000035421f0>::A,
    [2] Object < BasicObject,
    [3] PP::ObjectMixin,
    [4] Kernel,
    [5] BasicObject
]
~/rails/learn/ruby (main) > D.new.cancel!
cancel from c:D
cancel from m:A
=> nil
```

I hope it helps with your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Just ask if super defined:

```
def cancel!
  cancelly_stuff
  super if defined?(super)
end
```

More information at [Avdi Blog](http://devblog.avdi.org/2010/09/24/checking-the-existence-of-a-super-method-in-ruby/)

**Edit**: I add a running example:

```
# calling_super.rb
module Superable
  def cancel!
    puts 'canceling from module: Superable'
    super if defined? super
    puts 'end of cancel from module: Superable'
  end
end

class WithoutSuper
  include Superable
end

class Cancelable
  def cancel!
    puts 'cancel from class: Cancelable'
  end
end

class Child < Cancelable
  include Superable
end
```

at my irb (tested on 1.9.2 and 2.1.1):

```
~/rails/learn/ruby (main) > require './calling_super'
=> true
~/rails/learn/ruby (main) > WithoutSuper.new.cancel!
canceling from module: Superable
end of cancel from module: Superable
=> nil
~/rails/learn/ruby (main) > Child.new.cancel!
canceling from module: Superable
cancel from class: Cancelable
end of cancel from module: Superable
=> nil
```

I think this is the behavior you are looking for.